# Prestashop Blockcart jQuery Delete Image Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, prestashop

in Blockcart, there is animation of adding. But when one deletes the product, there is no animation of image going back to the product if present.

Whereas when I go to mangoshoppers.com I see both these animations.

How to put this animation of remove product in my Prestashop website blockcart - my website is www.dailydeliver.com

Answer (score 1):

Prestashop doesn't support "delete product animation", the store you mention as example (mangoshoppers.com) is not using prestashop, is not even PHP.

Comment: The animation is a jQuery. Prestashop supports jQuery. There need to be some additions in the code for blockcart.js . I just don't know what to add to make it possible.